# Sensitivity vs Specificity examples

Tags: probability

I understand what each of them are but am having trouble with examples of tests which would each require a high degree of specificity...

I would think that pregnancy tests and a fatal disease test would require high sensitivity, so that there would be minimal false negatives. (Correct me if I'm wrong please)

However, I cannot think of a test or two which would want minimal false positives.

Comment: A test for a disease that is completely curable but requires a difficult or painful operation would be one example. You don't want false positives, because you'd end up putting people through the procedure for no reason. PSA testing is another good example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here. For typesetting equations please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).